# Going through a list with given keyword list and telling the index of the direct hits

Tags: python

I have a task that requires me to write a function `all` that has the following given arguments:

- `sourcelist`
- `keywordlist`

I have to go through the `sourcelist` and return the index information of all of the matches in the `sourcelist`.

So what do I do?

The outcome for eg. is:

```
source = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','e']
keywords = ['b','d']
 
print(all(source,keyword))
# Return:
# [1, 3]
```

Comment: You shouldn't call your function `all()`, as there's a built-in function with the same name.

Comment: Hint: Use `enumerate()` to loop over the `source` list to get the indexes and values. Then test if the value is in `keywords`, and if so, add the index to the result list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.index` within a list comprehension

```
def all(src, keys):
    return [src.index(i) for i in keys]

>>> all(source, keywords)
[1, 3]
```

though you would need some extra error handling if you expect `keywords` to contain any elements that are not present in `source`.

Alternatively you could `enumerate` to get the index,value pairs from source and keep the ones that occur in keywords, though you would have to consider the expected behavior if duplicate entries were encountered.

```
def all(src, keys):
    return [idx for idx, val in enumerate(src) if val in keys]
```

Comment: Simpler is to loop over `enumerate(src)`

Comment: Please don't do someone's homework for them, they won't learn that way.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!!! YOU TOTALLY MADE MY DAY

Comment: Using `index` is quite inefficient, for each element you iterate over the list